# Errors when running Foursquare connected app on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mysql-python

I have searched this site and I have googled and I've done everything that every site has told me to do. I'm getting the following errors even though I've installed everything. I have installed PIL and the Imaging module but it's still not working. I'm still getting a 500 error when I go to the app url.

```
The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.
The database file stub is deprecated, and will stop being the default in a future 
release. Append the --use_sqlite flag to use the new SQLite stub.
WARNING data_file_stub py:518 Could not read datastore data from
/var/folders/6t/rl1gd6856w75zkcjy2cxjtfr0000gn/dev_appserver.searchindexes     
WARNING dev_appserver.py:3655 Could not initialize API imagaes; you are likely
missing the Python "PIL" module. Import Error: No module named _imaging
```

Comment: Could you perhaps edit your question to include your code (or link to your code if it's really long)?

Comment: I uploaded the repo at github the url is http://github.com/jennifermcdaniel/friendishome Thanks for your help!